# Discord.js | How do I make that so it enters a new line every 2 or 3 words?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, https

I tried to make a random words command, and I'm also new to this Discord js. So.. sorry about my bad stinky code. My code is

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    commands: 'randomWords',
    minArgs: 1,
    maxArgs: 1,
    expectedArgs: '<Number>',
    
    callback: async (message, arguments, text, client) => {

        const request = require('request');
        const https = require('https');

        if (!isNaN(arguments[0])) {
            var url = `https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=${arguments[0]}`
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Please input a number. ex. 24")
        }


        // Get data from link 

        https.get(url, resp => {

            let data = '';


            // chunk of data been received
            resp.on("data", chunk => {
                data += chunk
            })

            resp.on("end", () => {
                let dataIn = JSON.parse(data);

                var dataInString = dataIn.toString()
                var datas = dataInString.replace(/,/g, " ")
                // here you add a new line every 2 words or 3 words
                console.log("\n\n\n" + datas + "\n\n\n")
                // i know i suck at this, but my terminal was very filled and so confused reading so added spaces

                // send the message

                const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`Random Words: ${arguments[0]}`)
                .setDescription(`this right here is supposed to be advertisement, so i deleted it for stack overflow \nWord Separated by spaces`)
                .addFields(
                    { name: "Words:", value: datas },
                    {name: "Invite Bot Below", value: "invite bot advertisement blocked"}
                )


            
                message.channel.send(embed)
            })


        })        
        
    }
}
```

The problem is in the callback, the command handler doesn't matter

Problem is in around line 38

Really appreciate if yo helped me out :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let words = ["hello", "test", "ice", "cream", "fast", "food"];
let str = "";

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 === 0) str += words[i] + " ";
  else str += words[i] + "\n";
}

console.log(str);
```

Maybe this example could help you with your problem. The for-loop iterates through the array. If `i` is an equal number, it just prints out the values without a new line. Else if `i` is not an equal number it prints out the value, but with a new line.

The output of this is:

```
hello test
ice cream
fast food
```